# How to launch and run a UWP app in the background

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am developing a UWP app but I want it to run completely in the background and launch hidden with the exception of perhaps a notification tray icon.

I'm not even sure where to start as this is my first venture into UWP and I cannot seem to change the entry point in the manner I want.

Answer (score 0):

With [background tasks](http://Support%20your%20app%20with%20background%20tasks) your app can work in background and wake up after some conditions

For your needs you can [run a background task on a timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-on-a-timer-)

Comment: How does this keep the window from being visible when launched?

Comment: When app is launched it would be visible, but after closing it would still work in background without notification icon, but with possibility to send notification